# Is it possible to recover induction for nat from W-types?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types, inductive-datatypes

W-types generalize the [type of well-founded trees](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/W-type), i.e., possibly infinetely branching trees. I understand that inductive types may be encoded as such in dependent type theory (CIC, MLTT, etc), [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/55674/48157) being particularly helpful in that, but is it possible to derive the usual induction principles from those? E.g., consider the following code in Coq:

```
Inductive W (A: Type) (B: A -> Type): Type :=
  | sup:
    forall a: A, (B a -> W A B) -> W A B.

Definition nat: Type :=
  W bool (fun b =>
    if b then
      (* Zero recursive arguments *)
      False
    else
      (* One recursive argument. *)
      unit).

Definition O: nat :=
  sup _ _ true (False_rect _).

Definition S (n: nat): nat :=
  sup _ _ false (fun _ => n).

Lemma nat_rect:
  forall P: nat -> Type,
  forall H1: P O,
  forall H2: (forall n, P n -> P (S n)),
  forall n, P n.
Proof.
  admit.
Admitted.
```

It seems that I can't show that, e.g., the function for O is $\bot$-elimination, even though (I believe) it's the only possible function to write at that point. If it's not possible to do that in Coq, would it be possible in HoTT/CTT?

Comment: The HoTT book has a chapter on this and I'm fairly sure that they show how to derive induction types for all the core types that they introduce.

Comment: @Jake, I must say I have never actually read the HoTT book so far. Maybe it's about time I do so.

Comment: You need function extensionality in order to show that two trees are equal if they have the same branching type and equal subtrees.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, ohh! You're right! By using funext I've been able to show that induction holds (for nat as well as for trees, which take 2 recursive elements). So, as funext is a theorem in CTT, this is derivable in it. Thank you! :D

Comment: If Coq had eta rule for the unit type, it would be possible to define `nat` from `W` without funext, with exactly the same computational behavior as expected: https://jashug.github.io/papers/whynotw.pdf. Agda has the required eta, but not Coq.

Comment: @AndrásKovács: Ah yes, I forgot about Jasper Hugunin's gem!